# If I have a choice of 5 answers, how can hide the answers that were not selected?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am very new to using InfoPath so stick with me...I am wondering if it is possible to hide selections that were not chosen?

**Example:**  If I am scoring a certain criteria 5 through 1 and I have a description for each, how can I only show the description that was selected.  I would prefer to not use the dropdown menu feature because that limits the number of characters (I think).  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a section for each description.  Then create a formatting rule for each section that hides it unless the criteria is selected.

Here are the steps:

1. On the home tab of the ribbon, under controls, select the desired amount of section containers.
2. Still on the home tab of the ribbon, under rules, select "Manage Rules".
3. For each newly created section, click the section, and in the Rules dialog on the right hand side of your screen, click New >> Formatting and create a rule that hides the container when your criteria is not selected.